# Is there a way to make this MySQL query more efficient?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
select * from q_and_a qa 
where keyword = :keyword_top 
  or id in (
    select qk.question_id 
    from question_keywords qk 
    inner join q_and_a qa on qa.id = qk.question_id 
    inner join keywords k on k.id = qk.keyword_id 
    where k.keyword = :keyword_bottom 
  )
```

Comment: Query tuning questions are common here you should go read some of them. And the comments. Then come back and ask the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your query correctly, you don't need the subquery, but rather `outer joins`:

```
select q.*
from q_and_a q
    left join question_keywords qk on q.id = kq.question_id 
    left join keywords k on k.id = gk.keyword_id
where q.keyword = :keyword_top or 
    k.keyword = :keyword_bottom
```

You may need to use `distinct` with this, depends on the sample data and desired results.

---

Actually since this is really a question about performance, this may or may not make it faster.  As usual, it just depends.

A couple other variations  to your existing query would include using `exists` or using `union all` instead of `or`.  You have to run the comparisons to see what works best in your situation.  Also your indices and  keys need to be defined appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It might be cleaner for the sql engine to do this as a left join as opposed to you doing a subquery.

```
SELECT qa.* 
FROM   q_and_a qa 
       LEFT JOIN question_keywords qk 
              ON qa.id = qk.question_id 
       LEFT JOIN keywords k 
              ON k.id = qk.keyword_id 
WHERE  qa.keyword = :keyword_top 
        OR k.keyword = :keyword_bottom
```